# What is the best method to break this into usable strings

Tags: ios, arrays, nsstring

Whats is the best way to parse this out?

**String:**
     `UMversion=2.9&UMstatus=Approved&UMauthCode=152058&UMrefNum=59567592&UMavsResult=Address%3A%20Match%20%26%205%20Digit%20Zip%3A%20Match&UMavsResultCode=YYY&UMcvv2Result=Match&UMcvv2ResultCode=M&UMresult=A&UMvpasResultCode=&UMerror=Approved&UMerrorcode=00000&UMcustnum=&UMbatch=1&UMbatchRefNum=91016&UMisDuplicate=N&UMconvertedAmount=&UMconvertedAmountCurrency=840&UMconversionRate=&UMcustReceiptResult=No%20Receipt%20Sent&UMprocRefNum=&UMcardLevelResult=A&UMauthAmount=10&UMfiller=filled`

I get this back from the web service as one big long string.  Each of the variables are listed then they have `a = sign` then what I need to populate the variable with.

I need to get all of this data into variables to check them.

So, how should I go about breaking it down.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: Looks like the post section of a http response. Show a bit of code where you actually receive this data and I bet that somebody will have a hint for you.

Comment: The code side is not going to help.  It just gets put into a variable, this is where the question starts

Comment: Look into `NSString componentsSeparatedByString:`

Comment: @rmaddy that mean you would have to run it through several times to get the data out properly.

Comment: Yes it does. That's what `for` loops are used for.

Comment: @rmaddy But the question arrises, is that the best method or just the quick and dirty way?

Comment: Of course, another option would be a couple of passes of `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` followed by a pass through NSJSONSerialization.  (With stringByRemovingPercentEncoding maybe thrown in for good measure, though JSON deserialization should take care of that.)

Comment: @HotLicks care to go into that a little deeper.

Comment: I'm in up to my knees already.  (Replace `&` with `","` and `=` with `":"`, patch up the ends to make it look like a legit JSON "object", and deserialize.)

Comment: @Raymond There is no built in API to directly split a URL query string into a dictionary. Most people end up doing what I stated - use `componentsSeparatedByString` once with `@"&"` to get each pair then again with `@"="` to split each pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this kind of code:

```
NSArray* components = [veryLongString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"]; // array of strings like "x=y"
NSMutableDictionary* parsedResult = [NSMutableDictionary new];
for (NSString* keyValuePair in components) {
  NSArray* keyAndValue = [keyValuePair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
  NSString* key = keyAndValue[0];
  NSString* value = (keyAndValue.count>1) ? keyAndValue[1] : nil;
  // remove percent escapes in case we have URL-encoded characters in the value like '%20' and the like
  parsedResult[key] = [value stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ?: [NSNull null];
}

NSLog(@"dictionary of parameters: %@", parsedResult);
```

You will end up with a dictionary containing the keys and values extracted from your string.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant and extremely efficient.  Only had to fix one little thing in your code though.  keyAndValue.length>1 should be keyAndValue.count>1

Comment: @Raymond It's funny that you call this solution brilliant because you didn't seem to care for it when I suggested it in the comments. :) But this is exactly what I was talking about.

Comment: One issue with this solution. The last line of the `for` loop will cause a crash if `value` is `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString* firstPass = [sourceString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"\",\""];
NSString* secondPass = [firstPass stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"\":\""];
NSString* grandFinale = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"%@\"}"];
NSData* jsonSource = [grandFinale dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding];
NSError* error = nil;
NSDictionary* theBiggie = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonSource options:0 error:&error];
```

I think NSJSONSerialization will automagically fix up the percent encoding.  If not, run `grandFinale` through `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding`.

Comment: This is an interesting approach but is it possible for the URL to contain commas or other punctuation that will end up confusing the JSON parser?

Comment: @rmaddy - Other than the reserved `&` and `=`, I think it would only be confused by embedded quotes (and you could use a pass of replace `"` with `\"` for that).

Comment: But what if the existing values have a comma, colon, quote, curly brace, or parenthesis? There are a lot of possible things that could cause troubles trying to fudge the string into a JSON string.

Comment: @rmaddy - If they're within quotes they're OK.  My replacements insert the quotes.

Comment: Good point. I didn't notice that you were adding the quotes around each key/value. So that just leaves values that have a quote. Those would need to be escaped (which you mentioned earlier).